# Spring roo and GWT

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

Hey all,
I am trying to create an entity in spring STS with GWT scafolding. The entity is to be a superclass and abstract. When I tell roo to create the entity called Person, the following results.

```
~.model.Person roo> entity --class ~.model.Person --mappedSuperclass --abstract 
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\tt\edu\sbcs\model\Person.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\tt\edu\sbcs\model\Person_Roo_Configurable.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\tt\edu\sbcs\model\Person_Roo_Entity.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\tt\edu\sbcs\model\Person_Roo_ToString.aj
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA\tt\edu\sbcs\model\Person_Roo_ToString.aj
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA\tt\edu\sbcs\model\Person_Roo_Entity.aj
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA\tt\edu\sbcs\model\Person_Roo_Configurable.aj
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA\tt\edu\sbcs\model\Person.java
GWT does not currently support inheritence in proxied objects. Please remove the 'javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass' annotation from 'tt.edu.sbcs.model.Person' in order to complete 'gwt setup'.
~.model.Person roo>
```

So the question is: Is there a way to create an abstract supertype in Roo and still work with GWT? Can you say "Create the abstract entity but do not generate the GWT artifacts"?

Answer (score 1):

it is not a "GWT artifacts" it very specific thing GWT RequestFactory/EntityProxy framework that causes you troubles because as of GWT 2.1.1 inheritance of entities and its EntityProxies
try not to run "gwt setup" than it will not generate GWT related code but you will have your entities and stuff.

I know it looses most of the meaning to do so but this is seems to be the current deal with Roo & GWT.
the whole UI infrastructure that roo generates is based on RequestFactory